# Update ListView adapter in a fragment from outside the onCreateView method

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to build an app that populates ListView from JSON recievced. I'm getting the below exception when i try to update the listview using notifyDataSetChanged.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.example.android.Wordtrend.CustomArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()'
>   on a null object reference

The ListView is inside a fragment. Im using the onPostExecute method to call the update method inside the fragment to update the ArrayAdapter. UI loads the  dummy data provided in the onCreateView method but fails during updation.

Im a newbie, so any advice would be greatly helpful. Im confused because ArrayAdapter is null and the size of dataArray is zero inside the update method.

**Activity:**

public class ClassicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitycategory);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new ClassicFragment()).commit();
    }       
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class ClassicFragment extends Fragment {
    CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<dataobjects> dataArray=new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dataArray.clear();
        dataArray.add(new dataobjects("word","Explanation",R.drawable.placeholder,R.raw.color_black));
        dataArray.add(new dataobjects("word","Explanation",R.drawable.placeholder,R.raw.color_black));
        dataArray.add(new dataobjects("word","Explanation",R.drawable.placeholder,R.raw.color_black));

        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list,container,false);
        ListView listView=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(),dataArray,R.color.classic);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }


      public void update(ArrayList<FinalData> e){
         ArrayList<dataobjects> newDataArray=new ArrayList<>();  // update Adapter from JSON 
         for(int i=0;i<e.size();i++) {
           FinalData FinalDataObject = e.get(i);
           String word=FinalDataObject.getWord();
           String meaning=FinalDataObject.getMeaning();
           newDataArray.add(new dataobjects(word,meaning,R.drawable.placeholder,R.raw.color_black));         
          }

 Log.d("Classic"," Size of Data"+dataArray.size());   // Shows zero but im not clearing it manually. Should be two.


             dataArray.addAll(newDataArray);  // Size changes to 7 as expected.
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

// Calling update method from the class Dataprocess

```
public class Data extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        String Mdata;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Mdata=s;
            Dataprocess d=new Dataprocess();
            d.process(Mdata);
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }.....}
public class Dataprocess {

    Finaldata f;
    ArrayList<Finaldata> wordList=new ArrayList<>();
    ClassicFragment classicfragment=new ClassicFragment();
    public void process(String s ){
        if(s!=null){
            try {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray word = data.getJSONArray("WordArray");
                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = word.getJSONObject(i);
                    String word1=c.getString("word");
                    String meaning=c.getString("meaning");
                    f=new Finaldata(word1,meaning);
                    wordList.add(f);
                }
                classicfragment.update(wordList);
            }catch (Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomArray Adapter:**

```
    public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<dataobjects> {
        int color;
        public  static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        static AudioManager am;
        private TextToSpeech tts;

        static MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener oncom=new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                release();
            }
        };

        public CustomArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<dataobjects> a, int color) {
            super(context,0,a);
            this.color=color;
        }

        @Override

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View listitemview=convertView;
            if(listitemview==null){
                listitemview= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customlayout,parent,false);
            }
            dataobjects currentword=getItem(position);
            TextView t1=(TextView)listitemview.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            TextView t2=(TextView)listitemview.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            View background1=listitemview.findViewById(R.id.back);
            View background2=listitemview.findViewById(R.id.back2);
            background1.setBackgroundColor(colorid);
            background2.setBackgroundColor(colorid);
            int ex=currentword.getImageURL();
            int aud=currentword.getSound();
            t1.setText(currentword.getWord());
            t2.setText(currentword.getTransalation());
            int colorid= ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),color);

            ImageView im1=(ImageView)listitemview.findViewById(R.id.media);

            im1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     test();

                }
            });

            return listitemview;

        }
```

Comment: the key is where and how you call update(), and that part is missing!

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Edited the post with additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little convoluted, but basically what is happening is, when you call update() the fragment has not yet been initialized.

Read about a Fragment lifecycle.

In a nutshell:

- you create a fragment (like in your code with `new ClassicFragment()` ). So far, only the Fragment constructor has been called
- Then you insert it on the screen with a transaction, with something like

  **FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.add(frame.getId(), mFragment).commit();FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.add(frame.getId(), mFragment).commit();**
- Then, asynchronously, the fragment method `onAttach()` followed by others like `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()` will be called by the Android rendering engine.

In your code, the adapter is initialized in `onViewCreated()`, so only after the fragment is inserted and initialized you will be able to call `update()`. If you call `update` before, you will get a `NullPointerException` as the adapter has not yet been initialized.

You need to refactor your code, either detecting a call to update() when the fragment is not inited and postpone the update, or just calling update later.

Comment: Thanks rupps. As you mentioned before the way I called update method was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to put all your code inside the method onActivityCreated()

Answer (score 0):

use this method below in your fragment:

1. dataArray.clear();
2. dataArray = new ArraryList<>();
3. dataArray = getListBynet();   get the data from net
4. newAdapter=new CustomArrayAdapter(dataArray);
5. listView.setAdapter(newAdapter);

hope this is useful

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already have your adapter as a field on your fragment class, so you just need to have the following in your `CustomArrayAdapter`:

First add a field to your adapter for the `ArrayList` containing your data

`private ArrayList<dataobjects> data;`

and in your adapter constructor, set the value of that field from what you're passing in:

```
public CustomArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<dataobjects> a, int color) {
        super(context, 0, a);

        this.data = a;

        this.color=color;
    }
```

Then add a new method for changing the data in the adapter:

```
public void setItems(ArrayList<dataobjects> items){
    this.data = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And you'll also need to override `getItem()` to return the item from your `data` field.

```
@Override
public dataobjects getItem(int position){
    return this.data.get(position);
}
```

And then when you're updating your adapter later, just call `adapter.setItems(data);` from your fragment.

Hope it helps!